# How to convert mvc.play.Result to JsonNode or String

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.6

I am using play framework 2.6.17.
I have this class called "MasterTag" in controllers. The index function rin this class returns JsonNode(return ok(jsonNode)) value.

```
public class MasterTag extends Controller{
    public Result index(){
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonNode responseNode = mapper.readTree("{\"mastertag\":\"0.5\"}"); 
         return ok(responseNod);
    }
}
```

I have another class called "HomeController" in controller,in which there is a call to MasterTag.index(). This returns of the type play.mvc.Result

How do I extract the orginal JsonNode from the Result obtained by the above mentioned call?

Answer (score 2):

I dont have answer how to get the Json, but I finally know, how to get String from Result

1.

```
@Inject
Materializer materializer;

// this is another controller, I would like to get Result from
@Inject
URLExamplesController urlExampleContoller;
```

2.

```
public Result index() {

// how to convert Result into String
// caling function in another controller to get Result object
Result result = urlExampleContoller.getQuestyParameterExample2("test 123");
FiniteDuration finiteDuration = Duration.create(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
byte[] body = Await.result(
            FutureConverters.toScala(result.body().consumeData(materializer)), finiteDuration).toArray();

String outputOfAnotherController = new String(body);
}
```